# Change alt gr functionality

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys

When I updated from Ubuntu 18 to Ubuntu 20, I was asked to give up a keyboard shortcut to change character type (I actually don't exactly remember what it was, something with Latin input).  I choose the proposed alt gr button.

Now, after I updated, when I press <kbd>alt gr</kbd>, I am changing the keyboard layout.  I can't type the special characters anymore.  I can't seem to find a way to change this action.  In Settings/ region and language/ input source/ settings, I can see that there is a shortcut for right alt.  I can't find a keyboard shortcut for the right alt in keyboard settings.

Can anybody advise me what to do?

Comment: was it set up as a custom shortcut?

Comment: when I switch the language priority, pressing alt gr doesn't change the keyboard layout anymore (because it is the last one).  The alt gr works fine afterwards.  But this is somewhat of an artifical solution.  If somebody has another solution, feel free to share it.

Comment: @User24601 No, it was a standard request during the upgrade (reinstallment).